# How to clear the data in NebulaGraph Space?

Tags: nebula-graph

NebulaGraph Database version: 3.0.1
Please advise how to delete the data of nodes and edges in the Nebula Graph space. I deleted the nodes by `lookup` and pipe symbol, but I want to know how to clear nodes and edges together.

Answer (score 0):

You could DELETE vertex with the `WITH EDGE` option:

```sql
DELETE VERTEX <vid> [, <vid> ...] [WITH EDGE];
```

for instance:

```sql
DELETE VERTEX "player100" WITH EDGE;
```